# What does _r suffix mean?

Tags: c++, c, typing

I know  `_r` suffix is used to indicate something thread-safe. For example `strtok` and `strtok_r` or `libmysql.so` and `libmysql_r.so`. But I cannot find anywhere what this actually means ? For example, `_t` means 'type' and what does `_r` suffix mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See Chapter `A.4.16 Thread-Safety` in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/xrat/xbd_chap04.html:

> The suffix "_r" is historical, where the 'r' stood for "reentrant".

Answer (score 5):

The `_r` suffix stands for reentrant.

Answer (score 3):

`_r` means reentrant, even though those functions may not be really reentrant. Those functions just guarantee not to use static storage.

Comment: See also the discussion in the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8405940/371250