# What is the meaning of _r in PHP's print_r()?

Tags: php

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103410/what-does-r-suffix-mean) on so, but i'm not sure if it's the same for PHP... and if it is, what is the meaning of reentrant ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/print_r):

> print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable

so the answer is "**readable**"

Comment: Seems kind of obvious now that you put it this way. I guess you are right.

Answer (score 4):

From the PHP manual:

> print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable

The point of `print_r` is that it prints infos about a variable in a **human-readable** way, as opposed to `var_dump`, for instance...

So a good guess is that the **r** stands for **readable**.

Answer (score 1):

`print_r` will return any output is produces on the screen and produce a **human readable** format of an object

```
<?php
    $a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
    print_r ($a);
?>
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The _r stands for **readable**. This is visible when you display arrays in PHP. It shows a **nice identation** while doing so.